# Get the Audio Unit Components working folder on MAC OSX

Tags: c++, macos, core-audio

On a Mac in C++ you can use _NSGetExecutablePath to get the applications folder, but what if it´s an Audio Unit component file. How do I get the working folder of the component and not the hosts folder path?